# sumar las ventas de mis vendedores

Tags: mysql-workbench

Estoy trabajando en una base de datos que no está bien estructura y por falta de tiempo se necesita trabajar como esta, partiendo de esto quiero saber como sumar las ventas de mis vendedores, ya logre sacar que cantidad hizo en cada vena y lo que necesito es conseguir un solo total.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te recomiendo que visites [¿Cómo Preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para entender de mejor manera como armar tus preguntas y tener más éxito con las respuestas, como dice en el enlace anterior, sería completamente recomendable, que en lugar de una imagen pongas el código escrito, de modo que sea más fácil ayudarte!

Comment: ¿Necesitas sumar el todos los registros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer uso de la función SUM de mysql. A falta de información detallada en la pregunta, supongo que solo deseas visualizar el nombre del vendedor y el monto total. Ya que no has introducido el código de tu consulta me voy a limitar a indicarte los cambios nomas, ya que si intento copiarlo posiblemente cometa algún error de sintaxis.

```
SELECT SUM(total) as total_ventas, nombre_vendedor FROM 
... aquí van todas tus relaciones... 
GROUP BY nombre_vendedor;
```

Es muy **importante** que no olvides colocar el **GROUP BY**. Ya que sino vas a obtener el total de TODOS los vendedores, no se si me explico. Si no comprendes la respuesta te sugiero agregar el script para poder ayudarte mejor. Saludos!